# Как подружить wxWidgets и CLion (Windows + mingw-w64)?

Tags: c, cmake, сборка, clion, wxwidgets

Хочу сделать GUI приложение и выбрал для этого Си (без ++) и wxWidgets. Скачал с [офф.сайта](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) [установщик](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/download/v3.1.1/wxMSW-3.1.1-Setup.exe), поставил (Установился в `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1`, но я кинул рядом с исходниками папку с библиотекой в папке wx есть файл, который просится в коде).

[image: Пример 1][image: Ищчо пример]

Думал, что на этом всё, но нет, при попытке компиляции вылазит ошибка, что нет библиотеки.

Ошибка:

> "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.1.5\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Timoshka-WIN10\Documents\CLionProjects\GuiTEST\cmake-build-debug --target GuiTEST -- -j 1
>       [ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/GuiTEST.dir/main.c.obj
>       C:\Users\Timoshka-WIN10\Documents\CLionProjects\GuiTEST\main.c:3:10: fatal error: wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory
>        #include 
>                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       compilation terminated.
>       mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\GuiTEST.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/GuiTEST.dir/main.c.obj] Error 1
>       mingw32-make.exe[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX3hT.png):**  [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/GuiTEST.dir/all] Error 2
>       mingw32-make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm7yD.png):  **[CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/GuiTEST.dir/rule] Error 2
>       mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: GuiTEST] Error 2

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(GuiTEST C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(GuiTEST main.c)

target_include_directories ( GuiTEST PUBLIC
        $< BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}libs/wxWidgets-3.1.1/include >
        $< INSTALL_INTERFACE:libs/wxWidgets-3.1.1/include >  # <prefix>/include/mylib
        )
```

[Код с офф.сайта wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html)

```
// wxWidgets "Hello World" Program
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();
private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
};
enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
MyFrame::MyFrame()
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Hello World")
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
                     "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
    SetMenuBar( menuBar );
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
}
void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}
void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example",
                 "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}
void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

[Говорят, что надо что-то подшаманить в CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572328/getting-started-with-wxwidgets-and-clion), или [добавить `target_include_directories`](https://toster.ru/q/546201?e=6681221#answer_item_1245059), но в первом случае вроде под Ubuntu и не понятно, а во втором и по официальному мануалу для CMake тоже ничего не понятно :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target_include_directories( GuiTEST PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.1/include
```

Answer (score 3):

В CMake есть команда [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html?highlight=i). Поиск [wxWidgets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html) должен выглядеть так :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(MySuperProgram)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

У меня linux и этого вполне хватает чтобы скомпилировать проект Hello World.
Я wxWidgets не использовал. Но по описаниям он написан на C++. Даже в вашем примере код C++. Не уверен что будет легко использовать wxWidgets с языком С.

Comment: На Windows чот не работает ( https://hastebin.com/nihequboke.sql

Comment: У меня просто wxWidgets уже был установлен. А CMake смог его найти. У вас нужно будет указать где находится wxWidgets. С CMake я редко работал. Вроде нужно путь к wxWidgets указать через переменную wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR. Попробуйте в начале проекта прописать set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR /путь/к/wxWidgets).

Comment: Отложите Смайк, это добрый совет :) пробуйте сперва собрать тесты руками.